# JS or Css page slide transition between 2 full pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I have two html pages: Page1.html, Page2.html.
I would like to slide between the two pages. I have found a lot of plugins and solutions to slide between two divs or slide within a container but what I need is a complete page change.

[I found something](http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/) but the problem is that jquery code on page2 does not fire when the page loads. I could use jQuery  mobile but my project uses jQuery ui and it gives me some conflicts... so I need something else.

The project is supposed to run on iPad so it would be cool to have sliding pages that you can drag. But I would be happy to just find a plugin for the slide.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a mobile solution or a desktop one? or Both?

Comment: At the end, what did you choose? I am facing the same problem and I don't want to do it with jQuery because I need to load the html head. I think I am going to use CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You have few solutions, like using Ajax for adding content to "new pages" and add some sliding effect with jQuery. There is some topics about that on Stack Overflow:

[slide between pages using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518762/slide-between-pages-using-jquery)

[Clues on sliding between pages effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446921/clues-on-sliding-between-pages-effect)

Or just add some effect on page ready like in this sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body div').slideDown();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: blue; display: none;">
        <a href="page2.htm" style="color: white;">PAGE 2>></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body div').slideDown();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: red; display: none;">
        <a href="page1.htm" style="color: white;">PAGE 1>></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a full page transition vs. many examples that show one page with a couple of DIVs.  I found that Animate.css does the trick very well.

[Demo at this link.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/html-page-transitions-animiations)

[image]